# Comments not expanded by default?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design

On mobile web, the non-upvoted comments are not expanded by default, only on Workplace.se. No other site does this, including this Meta. Is this by design or a bug?

There is no user settable option for this.

[image]

Comment: I think [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2865/2322) is the reason for this?

Comment: This happens on desktop as well, so not just a mobile thing.

Comment: Also, on desktop at least, it definitely happens on other sites as well. Here are some examples on [SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164352/why-dont-lightsabers-have-guards), [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/93590/29336), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86914/what-is-a-logical-explanation-for-why-a-race-of-stone-humanoids-wouldnt-become). Can you verify whether the comments are expanded on these as well?

Comment: @ender so by design? Even when there is a single comment?

Comment: @David single un-upvoted comment on the worldbuilding and scifi link are not hidden.

Comment: @cde Interesting, they are hidden for me on desktop. And just tried my phone - hidden there too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comments without upvotes are now hidden if a question has more than two answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/comments-without-upvotes-are-now-hidden-if-a-question-has-more-than-two-answers)

Comment: That answers the question, but they are not dupes. This can be marked as status-by-design.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in StackOverflow (also in the mobile) low upvoted comments are hidden also, this is an expected behavior to make good comments stand out

Comment: @gray on most sites the first 5 un-upvoted comments are seen for every answer. The behavior here and on SO are the odd ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specific to mobile, and it's an intentional site-specific setting.  See [Comments without upvotes are now hidden if a question has more than two answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/comments-without-upvotes-are-now-hidden-if-a-question-has-more-than-two-answers).

The Workplace gets a lot of comments, and the default visibility settings led to a lot of noise on the page that got in the way of getting to the next answer.  So we now auto-collapse comments that aren't upvoted on questions with more than a couple answers, to help focus on the important content: the question and answers.